# Why Ruby on Rails 7.x.x doesn't render the public folder? Not favicons or 404.html page. I use my module but it doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use concern

```
module ErrorHandling
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :notfound

    private

    def notfound(exception)
      logger.warn exception
      render file: 'public/404.html', status: :not_found, layout: false
    end
  end
end
```

And include it on Application class include ErrorHandling but it doesn't render file: 'public/404.html' what is the problem?

I do all for fix this trouble but can't do something

Comment: What does your application's [`config.public_file_server.enabled`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#config-public-file-server-enabled) configuration look like?

Comment: Its true config.public_file_server.enabled = true

Answer (score 2):

When passing a relative path name to `render: file`, Raiuls will throw an `ArgumentError` with the following message:

```
`render file:` should be given the absolute path to a file. 'public/404.html' was given instead
```

The ability to pass relative paths here was [deprecated](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/35688) in Rails 6.0 finally [removed](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/d52d7739468153bd6cb7c629f60bd5cd7ebea3eb) with Rails 6.1.0.

To render a raw file, you should follow [the current documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#rendering-raw-file):

> Rails can render a raw file from an absolute path. This is useful for
> conditionally rendering static files like error pages.
>
> ```
> render file: "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", layout: false
> ```
>
> This renders the raw file (it doesn't support ERB or other handlers).
> By default it is rendered within the current layout.
>
> **WARNING**: Using the `:file` option in combination with users input can lead to security problems since an attacker could use this action
> to access security sensitive files in your file system.

Comment: I should use "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html"
=> "/Users/ivansizyh/Desktop/TechInterrogate/public/404.html" to accurately convey the path to the file?

Comment: Its not work(( I use  def notfound(exception)
      logger.warn exception
      render file: "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", status: :not_found, layout: false
    end and it on query Started GET "/ru/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2023-12-19 20:09:53 +0700
  
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/ru/1"):

Comment: this is [1] pry(main)> "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html"
=> "/Users/ivansizyh/Documents/AskIt/public/404.html" takes me to the page in the console but still the error is rooting error and not rendering the page from the public folder

Answer (score 0):

To fix it create an error controller:

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
  def not_found
    render file: "#{Rails.root}/public/404.html", status: :not_found, layout: false
  end
end
```

and add this to my `config/application.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')
config.exceptions_app = ->(env){ ErrorsController.action(:not_found).call(env) }
```

and add this in my `config/routes.rb`

match `'*path'`, to: `'errors#not_found'`, via: `:all`

[image]

I will of course try to do this with caution, but so far it hasn't worked

But now it does query the correct result

```
Processing by ErrorsController#not_found as HTML
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"ru", "path"=>"1"}
  Rendering public/404.html
  Rendered public/404.html (Duration: 0.2ms | Allocations: 87)
Completed 404 Not Found in 29ms (Views: 2.7ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 2772)
```